How do these nearly-periodic small clouds form?
I recently saw these clouds when flying:

I wonder what causes them to create these many small lumps -- intuitively, I would expect water vapor to form a more-or-less uniform mist with much vaguer boundaries, determined mainly by the wind. Does water congregate somehow? I cannot think of any mechanism for that.
From a look at Wikipedia, these might be Altocumuculus castellanus, but there's nothing about their formation process there.

I’m voting to close this question because this is more suited to [earthscience.se]

there's real physics in there: the size distribution & scale length of buoyancy-driven convection cells in a gravity field for example.

The clouds form when the temperature of a parcel of moist air reaches the dew point temperature. in this example, the height at which the clouds form is cooler than the surface beneath them, from which the moist air is rising. That's where the moisture condenses and the cloud is created.
Warmer air sitting beneath a layer of cooler air is dynamically unstable and the two air masses want to switch places, the exchange occurs via convective cells that spontaneously develop. The cloud pattern marks out the location of the cells in which the air is rising due to buoyant forces. each cell has a certain size that depends on the magnitude of the buoyant force, the viscosity of the air and the thickness of the heated air layer. (BTW the air between the rising cells is sinking towards the ground.)
